# Getting TFTP timeout in a Fuel / MAAS configuration

Tags: maas, pxe, tftp

We have a site that is utilizing Fuel/MAAS for deployment.  When attempting to PXE bootstrap the nodes we receive a "PXE-E32: TFTP open timeout".  PXE is set over a private lan and there is no firewall.

If I reboot the MAAS server, this issue clears up and I am able to PXE bootstrap but within 24 hours it stops working again.

I have checked the network and I am seeing no issues on it.

[PXE-E32 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLih3.jpg)

Comment: If you install `wireshark` and read the documents, you can, by running `wireshark` on the MASS server, watch the packets go back and forth during PXE boot attempt. Read them carefully, and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: As this is a Production environment I am not sure if I can install that.  I will see if I can.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Having the same issue, did a port scan and no tftp service is open.